# How to change/configure desired compiler in Qt creator? i.e. switch between MSVC/Mingw or g++/clang++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, mingw, qt-creator

I am aware about [how to add compiler in Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html). However my Qt always chooses MSVC compiler. How to set MinGW (built-in or external) instead of MSVC?

Couldn't find any post which can help a newbie to know how to change the compiler of desired preference. My current system is Windows, however information on Linux (g++ <--> clang++) is also welcome.

Comment: In the options for [Kits](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html) is a button on the right to `Make Default` the currently selected one.

Comment: Thanks @ssbssa,But i am not getting MinGW g++ compiler for windows desktop application to make it default.

Comment: Is the button not available, or is it doing nothing?

Comment: Thanks again @ssbssa, i got the idea, first i have to add manual compiler and then i can mark that compiler as default , as you have answered in first comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the way with Qt 5.9:

1. While configuring a new project, select only those compilers/kits which are required;
2. For 64-bit system, get the [latest MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/latest/download?source=rw_typ_t5) and install in a suitable path; While installing MinGW64, you may select *"posix threads"*, and not *"win32 threads"* to allow threading related libraries
3. Go to `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers` and add a manual C++ compiler. Choose the path of where you installed `C:/MinGW64/bin/g++.exe` (name it something like "MinGW64"); Similarly you may add C compiler as well with `C:/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe`; Click 'Apply'
4. In the same dialog box, select the `Debuggers` tab and similarly add `C:/MinGW64/bin/gdb.exe` (name it like "MinGW64 Debugger); Click 'Apply'
5. In the same dialog box, select the `Qt Versions` and add a new Kit with `MinGW64` like name; However I couldn't find an appropriate `qmake.exe` for it; Hence, I decided to use the same `qmake.exe`, which came with built-in 32 bit MinGW within Qt package (**not sure about this as of now**)
6. In the same dialog box, now select the `Kits` tab and add a new `Manual kit`; You may also follow the way the default MinGW32 bit compiler is configured; Configure `Compiler`, `Debugger` and `Qt Version` for this newly named kit; Click 'Ok'
7. On the left pan of Qt creator, click on "Projects" tab, and go to "Build & Run" option there; To avoid confusion, you may disable all the kits which are not required; Just keep the relevant kit and click "Build" with either "Debug" or "Release" setting