# Build 32 bit Qt application on 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit QT 5.9.1 with the compiler MSCV 2017 64 bit.

I am trying to build a 32 bit application in this environment and linking to a 32 bit library, but I can't seem to fight the correct combination of options to accomplish this nor do I know if this is even possible.

I've seen some solutions use

TARGET = 32bit_binary

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -m32

but I can't seem to figure out how to adapt it to this environment. Any tips?

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I have no internet access nor do I have admin rights on the machine that I am using so installing new versions is not possible.

My project is also a subdirs project with 3 different .pro files. When I make one change to one pro file, I usually apply the change to all of them.

**EDIT 2:** This is to resolve errors

LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function

I believe that once I can compile it in 32 bit, these errors will go away, but I am unsure if that is the case.

**EDIT 3:** I do have a 32 bit version of qt but it's in MINGW so it cannot properly find the QMAKE_MSC_VER and so on down the rabbit hole. If there are any tips on how to make it work with MSCV2017 that would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be possible, I do it all the time on Windows 10 64bit. But you will absolutely need a 32-bit kit of Qt installed on the system. There might not be a 32-bit kit for MSVC2017 but the 32-bit kit for MSVC2015 works for 2017 to. Please put any error messages you get in your question as they might contain clues to what is going wrong.

Comment: I added the errors that I am seeing and why I am attempting it this way to give further explanation

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem, you need a 32 bit kit for Qt. For that, you have to go to `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits`. However, if you just installed Qt 64 bit, this kit will most likely not be available. Thus, you should launch the Qt Maintainenance Tool from `Start -> Programs -> Qt -> Qt Maintenance Tool`. From here, you have to skip the Qt login, unless you are using a commercial version of Qt, and then click `Add or remove components`. Now you should select the kit that you want (Qt 32 bit), and Qt will install the(se) kits automatically. Once this is complete, then you can go back to the Kits menu and add them.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this solution doesn't work for me as I do not have admin rights on my machine and cannot install or remove programs easily. I have changed my original post to specify that.

Comment: I now have a 32 bit MinGW kit installed on my machine, but it won't let me select it when I am using the MSCV 2017 compilers. In fact when I created a custom kit using the MSCV 2017 compilers, it tells me there is an error with the kit and that the MSCV compiler cannot compile code with the MINGW version of QT.

Comment: That is very unusual; the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305485/how-to-change-configure-desired-compiler-in-qt-creator-i-e-switch-between-msvc) should work...

Comment: I think the issue is that the compiler I am selecting is Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.0 (x86_amd64) and Qt version QT 5.9.1 MinGW 32 bit. The error that I get says it cannot compile code for that and if I go to the compiler output it says it cannot find QMAKE_MSC_VER which is needed to compile or build. I followed the steps above but it does not resolve this specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the canonical text to put into your .pro file would be this:

```
CONFIG -= x86_64
CONFIG += x86
```

(The first line makes sure that building of 64-bit binaries won't happen, and the second line makes sure that building of 32-bit binaries will happen)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do much for me. I'm still getting similar errors to what I am getting before.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a 32 bit kit in Qt Creator to generate a 32 bit executable.

To configure your kits go to: `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits`.

After that, you can active the kit for your project.